# Sockets and multithreading with Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to allow two threads in an Android application to communicate with each other. Simple, right? I have two threads:

- The main thread controls the user
  interface of the application (Thread
  A)
- The other controls a TCP socket
  (Thread B)

At the moment, in order for Thread A to send messages to Thread B, I'm using a class with static instance data and static methods that can be set by Thread A. Thread B is using a loop to check for incoming data over the socket, so I used the same loop to check for a change in that supplementary class. That's how I managed to send data from Thread A to Thread B. However, I'd also like Thread B to be able to notify Thread A, the main user interface thread, that the socket has been closed, and act on that. Unfortunately though, Thread A isn't using any loops to check something continuously. So my question is, how do I notify Thread A of a change in Thread B? I've done searches and found that the Observer pattern would be useful, but I'm not sure that I can bring the Observer pattern into my existing setup. Any help or guiding thoughts would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate a handler in your UI Thread (Thread A), and pass a reference of the handler to Thread B. When you want to notify Thread A of something, create a Message object and use the handler to `sendMessage()`.

Example of a very simple pattern [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html)

Check official docs for Handler and Message classes

google for Android handler tutorial